# How to create a scheduled GET request and send Notifications when the app is in background?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotifications

I have a Web-Service application, i need to send scheduled GET methods to my server and if a change has happened with my incoming data i have to inform my user about the changes. When my app is in the foreground(in min thread) i fetch some data and pıpulate my tableview, my problem is, i can't realize how to create a scheduled method to the same data source(mean server) and if a new thing has been added, either my app is on bacground or not, inform user(alert) about the changes. Can anyone please share any idea-link.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what push notifications were designed for, and are, technically the best way to solve the problem.

It does mean the task of 'checking' for new data is shifted to your server but the user is better suited as a push notification will happen, even if your app is not running.

I recommend using a system like Urban Airship.

Comment: But as far as i understood from Apple's Push Notifications Guide, it is never guaranteed that the notification has been received by the client. For this i want to control  the server every 2 minuts, even if my app is in background.

Comment: If you want a more elaborate system then you could use a VOIP socket and the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:^{}] call, however be aware A> your app may be rejected because of it and B> it can only wake up once every 10 minutes and C> it will Kill the users battery. Remember: If you use APNS to send an update every time the user has new info to check, (and keep relevant counts of unread info) one of the pushes will alert the user in a timely fashion...

Comment: But i have designed all my server side with php and it needs to be given whitin this week. I will not usel-sell it on AppStore, so it is not such a big matter-and so do the battery too. But restriction for just ten minutes is a great problem for me